# Table-valued parameter to be used in two stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameter-passing, ssms

I wrote a stored procedure to insert values into a table-valued parameter.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_timezone_table
    @TZ NVARCHAR(10)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Table CT_sp;

    IF type_id('[dbo].[COUNTRY_TIMEZONE_sp]') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TYPE [dbo].[COUNTRY_TIMEZONE_sp];

    CREATE TYPE COUNTRY_TIMEZONE_sp as TABLE (country_code NVARCHAR(2)) 

    INSERT @Table (country_code)
        SELECT country_code
        FROM Timezones
        WHERE fo_timezone = @TZ
END
```

Then I want to pass this as input for another stored procedure, using in the end  in the WHERE clause like this:

```
WHERE country_code IN (SELECT country_code FROM @TimezoneTable)
```

This is not yielding what I want, so I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to make a simple select on the table-valued parameter to see exactly what fell inside there on the 1st procedure?
2. I reckon this can be a problem of missing quotes on the strings being passed in the IN clause.. How can I solve this problem? Anyway I can in the first stored procedure add the results of the other table concatenated with '' ?

   WHERE country_code IN (SELECT country_code FROM @TimezoneTable)

I guess it is doing something like IN ( DE,PL) so it retrieves blanks, and it should be doing IN ('DE','PL') but I do not know how to put the country_codes in quotations

Thank you!

Comment: Quotes are required only around string literals, not variables. I don't see any string literals anywhere in your code other than `'[dbo].[COUNTRY_TIMEZONE_sp]'`

Comment: I mean here: 
WHERE country_code IN (SELECT country_code FROM @TimezoneTable)
I guess it is doing something like IN ( DE,PL) so it retrieves blanks, and it should be doing IN ('DE','PL')  but I do not know how to put the country_codes in quotations

Comment: Why do you ask if it's possible to select from the TVP?   Did you try and get an error?   What was your code and what was the error?

Comment: No. You don’t have to put in quotes. I promise.

Comment: You are right. It is working, I must have forgotten to declare something.
Anyway, my issue now is that I want to reset my TVP each time I ran the SP, as I will run the SP in different times a day depending on the country. After the SP runs does the TVP gets truncated? Or the values inserted into them remains always there?